# Copy content of one table to another in MYSQL with store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, copy

I am trying to create a stored procedure to copy the entire content of a table to another

```
CREATE PROCEDURE copytbl
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `comparison2` (`id`, `Split/Skil`, `Skill State`, `Agents Staffed`, `Calls Waiting`, `Oldest Call Waiting`, `ACD Calls`, `Avg ACD Time`, `Aban Calls`, `Avg Aban Time`, `Avg Speed Ans`, `ABANDON30`)
SELECT * FROM `comparison`
END
```

Both table have the same format, I keep getting this error when trying to create the procedure:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'BEGIN  INSERT INTO `comparison2` (`id`, `Split/Skil`, `Skill
>   State`, `Agents Sta' at line 2

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS copytbl$$
CREATE PROCEDURE copytbl()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `comparison2` (`id`, `Split/Skil`, `Skill State`, `Agents Staffed`, `Calls Waiting`, `Oldest Call Waiting`, `ACD Calls`, `Avg ACD Time`, `Aban Calls`, `Avg Aban Time`, `Avg Speed Ans`, `ABANDON30`)
    SELECT * FROM `comparison`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To execute the procedure:

```
CALL copytbl();
```